# Subclass Method That Generates Different Message If Input Len > 20

Tags: python, class, input, subclass, string-length

I'm trying to create a chatbot that can engage in simple conversation with a human. The chatbot needs a subclass, `BoredChatbot`, that inherits the Chatbot as a superclass, but generates the following message if the user's input is greater than 20 characters long:

```
“zzz... Oh excuse me, I dozed off reading your essay.”
```

So far I have:

```
class Chatbot:
    """ An object that can engage in rudimentary conversation with a human. """

    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name

    def greeting(self):
        """ Returns the Chatbot's way of introducing itself. """
        return "Hello, my name is " + self.name

    def response(self, prompt_from_human):
        """ Returns the Chatbot's response to something the human said. """
        return "It is very interesting that you say: '" + prompt_from_human + "'"


# define a class called BoredChatbot

class BoredChatbot(Chatbot):

    def bored(self):
    """ Returns the Chatbot's response to length > 20 characters"""
        if len(prompt_from_human) > 20:
            return "zzz... Oh excuse me, I dozed off reading your essay."
        else: 
            return(response)

sally = Chatbot("Sally")
human_message = input(sally.greeting())
print(sally.response(human_message))
```

This isn't working - it prints:

```
"It is very interesting that you say: + human_message"
```

regardless of the length.

I also tried to switch the order of the if statement so that it appears outside of the method.

```
class BoredChatbot(Chatbot):

def bored(self):
    """ Returns the Chatbot's response to length > 20 characters"""
    return "zzz... Oh excuse me, I dozed off reading your essay."  

sally = BoredChatbot("Sally")
human_message = input(sally.greeting())

if len(human_message) > 20:
    print(sally.bored(human_message))
else: 
    print(sally.response(human_message))
```

But this gave me an error message:

```
AttributeError: 'Chatbot' object has no attribute 'bored' on line 31
```

Why isn't it registering bored from the method within `BoredChatbot`? Thanks for helping me clear this up - I feel like it's really close.

Comment: `class Chatbot` has no `bored` function...

Comment: Plus, you never created a `BoredChatbot` anyway

Comment: Oh I thought when I did class BoredChatbot(Chatbot) that created inheritance + added whatever method I put within that class?

Comment: Did you mean to put `sally = BoredChatBot("Sally")`?

Comment: Yes, that is inheritance. But inheritance doesn't do what you seem to think it does.

Comment: @Natecat Yes, I'll edit that now

Comment: If `BoredChatbot` implemented  `def response` (therefore overriding the function) itself, and you check the length there, then I think that is what you are going for. Adding a `bored()` function doesn't seem to be correct

Comment: Also, the way you've defined `BoredChatbot` will give you a `SyntaxError` because your docstring is not indented, and two `NameErrors`, one because `prompt_from_human` isn't definied, and the same thing for `response`

Comment: @HappyHands31 Try running that code

Comment: Where is `prompt_from_human` defined?

Comment: @Natecat I was getting some error messages at first but was able to fix them - it works now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So, let's look here.

```
class BoredChatbot(Chatbot):

    def bored(self):
    """ Returns the Chatbot's response to length > 20 characters"""
        if len(prompt_from_human) > 20:
            return "zzz... Oh excuse me, I dozed off reading your essay."
        else: 
            return(response)
```

What is `prompt_from_human`? How do you get that from `bored(self)`? Also `return(response)` is going to throw some error because 1) `self.response()` is the actual function, but 2) `response` is not defined either.

---

So, fixing those problem, I don't really think you need a `bored` function at all. You should instead override the `response` function and return the super function in order to keep your object functions consistent.

```
class BoredChatbot(Chatbot):

    def response(self, prompt_from_human):
    """ Returns the Chatbot's response to length > 20 characters"""
        if len(prompt_from_human) > 20:
            return "zzz... Oh excuse me, I dozed off reading your essay."
        else: 
            return super(BoredChatbot, self).response(prompt_from_human)
```

Then `sally = BoredChatBot("Sally")`, of course

Comment: My problem was that I assumed a subclass inherited the parameters from the methods in the super class. After you explained that I needed to override response and return the super function it made sense. Thanks for your help!

Comment: It does if you define them :) In order to override a function, it needs to have the same signature